# Why is mysql run in server-client model?

Tags: mysql, sqlite

From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657829/error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run

> Please make sure that you have installed the mysql-server, not the mysql-client or something else.

Why (for what purposes) is mysql run in server-client model?

Is sqlite also run in server-client model?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL operates in a networked environment using a client/server architecture. In other words, a central program acts as a server, and various client programs connect to the server to make requests.

MySQL Server, or mysqld, is the database server program. The server manages access to the actual databases on disk and in memory. MySQL Server is multi-threaded and supports many simultaneous client connections. Clients can connect via several connection protocols. For managing database contents, MySQL Server features a modular architecture that supports multiple storage engines that handle different types of tables (for example, it provides both transactional and non-transactional tables).

Note : But sqlite in just no sql file where it can br read and write to  main certain amount of data. Similar to excel sheet storage